# How to specify filename in DB2 CLP interactive input mode?

Tags: db2, clp

I want to exec script.sql inside DB2 interactive input (DB2 =>)

I can only initiate db2 using `krun -- db2`

And for some reason `krun -- db2 -vf script.sql` doesn't seem to work.

Only interactive mode works for me. Help.

Comment: I don't understand why you have tagged this with the "clp" tag - what does your question have to do with a CLP (Command Language Programming on IBM iSeries machines) program?

Comment: @BennyHill CLP is also an acronym for *Command Line Processor*, which is what the OP is talking about.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave the actual error that you receive.  You're using `krun` as a wrapper for the `db2` command, so the problem could be with how `krun` sets up the environment, a simple file path issue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the GET_LINE Built-in module for Oracle Compatibility. It is not available in Express-C edition.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0053534.html